# POST From without page reload [Flask] - Other methods no work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

I have tried MANY different ways to stop page reloading when I click a button to submit my form. The code below will show what form I have and what I am trying. I also am using Flask btw. My end goal is to simply hide and submit forms when the button is clicked WITHOUT refreshing the page (so the logic will be done in background)

```js
{% for id in output %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#form_{{id}}');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
{% endfor %}
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
          integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Product Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Newly Generated KeyWords</th>
      <th scope="col">Current Products Keywords</th>
      <th scope="col">Apply to These as Well</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Product Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Newly Generated KeyWords</th>
      <th scope="col">Current Products Keywords</th>
      <th scope="col">Apply to These as Well</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    {% for id in output %}
    <tr>
    <form id="form{{id}}" name="form_{{id}}" action="/execute_keywords" method="POST">
      <td><div><label for="to"></label> <input class="input" id="id" type="text" name="id" value="{{id}}"  /></div>  <a href="https://store-{{store_hash}}.mybigcommerce.com/manage/products/{{id}}/edit" target="_blank" class="btn btn-link"><br><button type="button" class="button is-link">View on BigCommerce</button></a></td>
      <td><div><label for="to"></label> <textarea class="textarea" name="keywords" id="keywords" rows="5"/>{{output[id]}}</textarea></div></td>
      <td><div><label for="to"></label> <textarea style="color:black" class="textarea" rows="5"/ disabled>{{curr_keywords[id]}}</textarea></div></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="meta_keywords" id="meta_keywords" value="YES" > <label for="meta_keywords">Meta Keywords</label><br><input type="checkbox" name="meta_desc" id="meta_keywords" value="YES" > <label for="meta_desc">Meta Description</label></td>
    <td><div><button id="status_{{id}}" name="status_{{id}}" class="button is-link" type="submit">Accept</button></div></td>
</form>
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating individual event handler for all forms you can keep only one event handler . Then , inside this use `$(this)` to refer current form where submit button has been clicked and then get required values from that form .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(ev) {
  var this_ = $(this) //current form..
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log(this_.serialize())
  $.ajax({
    type: this_.attr('method'),
    url: this_.attr('action'),
    data: this_.serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      alert('ok');
      this_.closest("tr").hide() //to hide whole tr..
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Product Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Newly Generated KeyWords</th>
      <th scope="col">Current Products Keywords</th>
      <th scope="col">Apply to These as Well</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Product Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Newly Generated KeyWords</th>
      <th scope="col">Current Products Keywords</th>
      <th scope="col">Apply to These as Well</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <form id="form1" name="form_1" action="/execute_keywords" method="POST">
        <td>
          <div><label for="to"></label> <input class="input" type="text" name="id" value="1" /></div>
          <a href="https://store-{{store_hash}}.mybigcommerce.com/manage/products/{{id}}/edit" target="_blank" class="btn btn-link"><br><button type="button" class="button is-link">View on BigCommerce</button></a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div><label for="to"></label>
            <!--here is textrea plese remove that `/` -->
            <textarea class="textarea" name="keywords" rows="5">abcdsds</textarea>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div><label for="to"></label> <textarea style="color:black" class="textarea" rows="5" / disabled>xyz</textarea></div>
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="meta_keywords" id="meta_keywords" value="YES"> <label for="meta_keywords">Meta Keywords</label><br><input type="checkbox" name="meta_desc" id="meta_keywords" value="YES"> <label for="meta_desc">Meta Description</label></td>
        <td>
          <div><button id="status_1" name="status_1" class="button is-link" type="submit">Accept</button></div>
        </td>
      </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <form id="form2" name="form_2" action="/execute_keywords" method="POST">
        <td>
          <div><label for="to"></label> <input class="input" id="id" type="text" name="id" value="2" /></div>
          <a href="https://store-{{store_hash}}.mybigcommerce.com/manage/products/{{id}}/edit" target="_blank" class="btn btn-link"><br><button type="button" class="button is-link">View on BigCommerce</button></a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div><label for="to"></label> <textarea class="textarea" name="keywords" id="keywords" rows="5">abcd2</textarea>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div><label for="to"></label> <textarea style="color:black" class="textarea" rows="5" / disabled>xyz2</textarea></div>
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="meta_keywords" id="meta_keywords" value="YES"> <label for="meta_keywords">Meta Keywords</label><br><input type="checkbox" name="meta_desc" id="meta_keywords" value="YES"> <label for="meta_desc">Meta Description</label></td>
        <td>
          <div><button id="status_2" name="status_2" class="button is-link" type="submit">Accept</button></div>
        </td>
      </form>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! Why do you need to serialize the form?

Comment: To send values of inputs as key value pairs . Check [this](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to know more

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me understand.